# Is there an idiom that means "x making barely enough money to live"?

Tags: idiom-request

I am wondering if there's an idiom that means that you are making barely enough money to live. Sometimes, I want to tell my co-workers that I am having a hard time with money, but I don't know how to say it well. Is there an idiom for that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many:

> They are barely **scraping by**.
>
> They are barely **getting by**.
>
> They **eke out** a life for themselves.
>
> They are barely **making ends meet**.
>
> They are **living hand-to-mouth**.

Related, colorful expressions for any trying circumstance:

> They are **hanging on by their fingernails**.
>
> They manage to keep going **by the skin of their teeth**.
>
> They are living **on a wing and a prayer**.

Plus many others.  I'll add more as I think of them.

Comment: Excellent list. I'd say that **scraping by**, **getting by**, and **making ends meet** are the most common I've seen/heard used.

Comment: Living hand-to-mouth.

Comment: **Living paycheck to paycheck**, which means, in addition to barely making enough money, that you have little or no savings and need your next paycheck to pay the bills.

Answer (score 2):

The one I know is **to be hard up**.

According to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hard-up):

> **hard up** (adjective) - having very little money: We're a bit hard up at the moment so we're not thinking about holidays.